# Trouble installing PyTorch for CUDA 9.0

Tags: python, pytorch, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install `PyTorch` for `CUDA 9.0` (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I followed instructions as per [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/), which says

Download the `whl` file with the desired version from the following html page:
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/torch_stable.html

```
$ pip install [downloaded file]
```

But above link is broken, I am unable to open it.

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting.

Comment: @Andy_101 No error, Link cannot open thats all.

Comment: You should probably contact pytorch website/github about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/torch_stable.html is a list of `<a href>` tags, which we can see by going into the source from the browser. We can then download the appropriate version and install via `pip install [downloaded file]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the link from

https://pytorch.org/

Its the easiest and best way to get what you want.

If cuda 9.0 is not working then try non cuda or cuda 9.2

Comment: I am using the official link only https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

Comment: Non CUDA will be extremely slow

Comment: then why not use cuda 9.2?

Comment: Because I also use `tensorflow-gpu v1.12` which doesn't suppoprts `CUDA-9.2`

Answer (score -1):

According to the [official documentation](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) you can install pytorch with command

```
# for Python 3.x
pip3 install torch torchvision
```

or if you prefer Python 2

```
# for Python 2.x
pip install torch torchvision
```